# How to dynamically show more or less fragments within 1 activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, ui-design

My app has a log_in activity, a main activity, and a settings activity.

The main `activity` is currently working by flowing between multiple fragments:

In the first `fragment`, the user selects a topic (from a dynamically-populated `recyclerview` of `cardviews`), the topic is then parceled and sent to the second fragment.

The second `fragment` displays the appropriate list (another dynamically-populated `recyclerview` of `cardviews` (formatted very differently, with different `cardviews`). The user can go back to the first fragment and choose another topic, and that choice is again parceled and sent to the second fragment to display the relevant list etc.

I want to set up the 2nd "page" so that it has 1 `fragment` at the top, which covers the top 80% of the screen, and 1 fragment at the bottom, which covers the bottom 20% of the screen, while still having only 1 fragment on the first "page" that covers 100% of the screen.

This is how I'm switching between each fragment in the flow right now:

main.java

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("itemlist", itemlist);
fragment = new fragment_2();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
```

And my activity_main.xml (for the main activity) has this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorBG"
    tools:context="com.app.activity.main">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So main_container is the FrameLayout that I'm replacing with the relevant fragment.

I can't find any clean example of a way to do this, can anyone show me?

The only thing I can think of is to have 2 FrameLayouts in the activity_main.xml, and have the 2nd container start as layout_width="0" and layout_height="0", but I feel this is a bad way to do it. Is there any way to replace the LinearLayout itself with another LinearLayout that has 2 FrameLayouts in it, and then assign the appropriate fragments to those containers?

Or what is the best way to do it?

I want to do things "the right way" (so I do not want to have separate activities) and I'm targeting API 16, but I may be willing to go up to API 23/24.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weightSum` property of LinearLayout to divide in 80:20 ratio.

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For using the same layout where you want to give 100% you can set the visibility of `frame2` to `GONE` and can dynamically set the layout of `frame1` to `3` (total of `weightSum` which will make it 100%).